# Unable to print the message sent from user space C application to Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, application, kernel-modules, embedded-linux

I have developed a simple Linux kernel module :

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>


ssize_t exer_open(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile) {

    return 0;
}



ssize_t exer_read(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {

    return 0;
}



ssize_t exer_write(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {

    return length;
}



ssize_t exer_close(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile) {

    return 0;
}




struct file_operations exer_file_operations = { 
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = exer_open,
    .read = exer_read,
    .write = exer_write,
    .release = exer_close,
};




int exer_simple_module_init(void) {

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Inside the %s function\n", __FUNCTION__);
    register_chrdev(240, "Simple Char Drv", &exer_file_operations);
    return 0;
}



void exer_simple_module_exit(void) {

    unregister_chrdev(240, "Simple Char Drv");
}

module_init(exer_simple_module_init);
module_exit(exer_simple_module_exit);
```

I insert this module to the kernel using `insmod` command without any problem.

I want to use this module to print a message sent to it by user space program that I have developed too :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>


int main()

{

int ret, fd;
char stringToSend[] = "Hello World !";


fd = open("/dev/char_device", O_RDWR);             // Open the device with read/write access

if (fd < 0)
    {
            perror("Failed to open the device...");
            return errno;
    }


ret = write(fd, stringToSend, strlen(stringToSend)); // Send the string to the LKM

if (ret < 0)
    {
            perror("Failed to write the message to the device.");
            return errno;
    }

return 0;

}
```

When I execute the program and examine the kernel logs using `tail -f /var/log/messages` command I can see : `user.alert kernel: Inside the exer_read` function But I cant see the message " `Hello World !`"

I don't know what I am missing here.  I am a beginner in developing modules and using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use copy_to_user and copy_from_user concept to read write data from userspace.